# Request for crazy integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, soft-question, big-list

I'm a sucker for exotic integrals like the one evaluated in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1046519/583016). I don't really know why, but I just can't get enough of the amazing closed forms that some are able to come up with.

So, what are your favorite exotic integral identities, and how do you prove them?

Comment: You may want to invest in this book. I am giving it to myself as a Christmas present

https://www.amazon.com/dp/0521796369/?tag=stackoverflow17-20&fbclid=IwAR2zdOpuW9aiUQINxOUmms-U6WYqGTWtdOhP-8EPC0v33RfGsrHeoXlnNZ4

Comment: You should refer to this question:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096701/nice-book-on-integrals

Comment: I know what you mean - I can't get enough of 'em either! There's that one that Peter Borwein likes to use in his demostrations: a product of progressively scaled _sinc_ functions, that's π/2 upto a certain point then starts to be a bit less. A _very very __tiny___ bit!

Comment: You can invent such integrals through "milking" techniques described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2821112/integral-milking). Perhaps [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2826594) is the most remarkable they found.

Comment: $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x\ln(\tanh(x))^2}{3\cosh(2x)-2e^{-2x}}\text{d}x
= -\frac{\pi^4}{96\sqrt{3} } -\frac{\ln3\ln^3(2+\sqrt{3} )}{24\sqrt{3} }
-\frac{\pi^2}{12\sqrt{3} }\operatorname{Li}_2\left (-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}   \right )
+\frac{\pi^2}{12\sqrt{3} }\operatorname{Li}_2\left (\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}   \right)
-\frac{\pi^2}{4\sqrt{3} }\operatorname{Li}_2\left (\sqrt{3}-2   \right)
-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3} }\operatorname{Li}_4\left (2-\sqrt{3}   \right)
+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3} }\operatorname{Li}_4\left (-2+\sqrt{3}   \right)$$

Comment: @aaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbcccccc wow. how do you get that one?

Comment: $\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\operatorname{arccot}\left(x\right)}{x^{2}-x-1}dx = -\frac{\left(\pi+2\arctan\left(2\right)\right)\operatorname{arccoth}\left(\sqrt{5}\right)}{2\sqrt{5}}$

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here are some of my favorites:
$$\int_0^\pi \sin^2\Big(x-\sqrt{\pi^2-x^2}\Big)dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(x)}{(1+x^{\sqrt 2})^\sqrt{2}}dx=0$$
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{(1+x^{1+\sqrt{2}})^{1+\sqrt{2}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \ln(2-2\cos(x^2))dx=-\sqrt{2\pi}\zeta(3/2)$$
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\text{erf}^2(x)}{x^2}dx=\frac{4\ln(1+\sqrt{2})}{\sqrt{\pi}}$$
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{3}\ln(e^x+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^2}{2}+x+1)-x^4}{\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^2}{2}+x+1}=\frac{\pi^2}{2}$$
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln(x^2+\ln^2(\cos(x)))dx=\pi\ln(\ln(2))$$
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(2x)+\arctan(x/2)}{x^2+1}dx=\frac{\pi^2}{4}$$
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin(x+100\tan(x))}{\sin(x)}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln(1+x+x^4+x^5)}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{\ln^2(2)}{2}$$
$$\int_0^{1/2}\sin(8x^4+x)\cos(8x^4-x)\cos(4x^2)xdx=\frac{\sin^2(1)}{16}$$

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{2+\cos(x)+\sqrt{5+4\cos(x)}}dx=4\pi$$

And here are four **extremely exotic** scrumptious integrals:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x^x (1-x)^{1-x}}dx=\frac{\pi}{e}$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{(e^x-x)^2+\pi^2}=\frac{1}{1+\Omega}$$

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{3\pi^2+4(z-\sinh(z))^2}{[3\pi^2+4(z-\sinh(z))^2]^2+16\pi^2(z-\sinh(z))^2}dz=\frac{1}{8+8\sqrt{1-w^2}}$$

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln|\sin(mx)|\ln|\sin(nx)|dx=\frac{\pi^3}{24}\frac{\gcd^2(m,n)}{mn}+\frac{\pi \ln^2(2)}{2}$$

...where $\Omega$ is the Omega Constant, $w$ is the Dottie Number, and $m,n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: Just the user I was hoping would answer! Thank you for your contribution, those integrals look delicious! :)

Comment: Are you sure that the $6$-th integral you listed (the one that evaluates as $\pi^2$) converges? The graph of it tells me otherwise...

Comment: @clathratus My apologies; the $-x^2$ should have been $-x^4$. I have fixed my answer so that the integral converges.

Answer (score 14):

Here are some links to a few integrals: [1](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/User:Integrals123)
(Big list, but not all of them got the right answer).
From AoPS: [2](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h1277222p6704015), [3](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1288609p6808007) , [4](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q2h1674162p10659982). Some that are solvable with Feynman's trick: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2987994/integration-using-the-feynman-trick/3000330#3000330).

As for my favourites (most of them appeared on [Romanian Mathematical Magazine](http://www.ssmrmh.ro/)), some are: $$I_1=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\arctan(\tan x\sec x)}{\tan x +\sec x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2 -\frac{\pi}{6}\ln(2+\sqrt 3)$$
$$I_2=\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{3x^2+15}{2x^2+18}\right)\cos\left(\frac{2x}{x^2+9}\right)\frac{dx}{x^2+1}=\frac{\pi}{e}$$
$$I_3=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 (1+x) (\ln^2 (1+x) +6\ln^2(1-x))}{x}dx=\frac{21}{4}\zeta(5)$$
$$I_4=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{(\pi^2+\ln^2 x)(1+x)^2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}=-\frac{\pi}{24}$$
$$I_5=\int_0^\infty \frac{1-\cos x}{8-4x\sin x +x^2(1-\cos x)}dx=\frac{\pi}{4}$$
$$I_6=\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan x}{x^4+x^2+1}dx=\frac{\pi^2}{8\sqrt{3}}-\frac{2}{3}G+\frac{\pi}{12}\ln(2+\sqrt{3})$$
$$I_7=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^4-x^2+1}dx=\frac{\pi}{6}\ln(2+\sqrt 3)+\frac23 G -\frac{\pi^2}{12 \sqrt 3}$$
$$I_8=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x^2)\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{\pi^3}{32}-3G\ln 2+\frac{\pi}{2}\ln^22.$$
$$I_{9}=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln\left(2+\sqrt{1-\tan^2 x}\right)dx = \frac{\pi}{2}\ln\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)+\frac{7\pi}{24}\ln2-\frac{\pi}{3}\ln\left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)-\frac{G}{6}$$
$$I_{10}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin \left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right) }{x+\frac{1}{x}}dx=\frac{\pi}{e^2}$$
$$I_{11}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos \left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right) }{\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{2e^2}$$
$$I_{12}=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1-x^4)}{x}dx=\frac{67}{32}\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi}{2} G$$
$$I_{13}=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x^2 \sqrt{\tan x}dx=\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi(5\pi^2+12\pi\ln 2 - 12\ln^22)}{96}$$
$$I_{14}=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} \operatorname{arcsinh} (\sin x) dx=G-\frac58\operatorname{Cl}_2\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)$$
$$I_{15}=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x \arcsin \left(\sin x-\cos x\right)dx=\frac{\pi^3}{96}+\frac{\pi}{8}\ln^2 2$$
$$I_{16}=\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(1+x+y)}{xy\left((1+x+y)(1+1/x+1/y)-1\right)}dxdy=\frac72 \zeta(3)$$
Where $G$ is Catalan's constant and $\operatorname{Cl}_2 (x)$ is the Clausen function.

Comment: These are really nice integrals. Thanks.

Comment: Cheers @Zacky! I too will be working on these!

Comment: Could I have a starter tip on $I_6$ and $I_7$? I'm very lost

Comment: For $I_6$ you can follow the same approach as seen here (it should be easier) https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2983399/515527.
For $I_7$ you can split the integral $\int_0^1 +\int_1^\infty $ and in the second one let $x=\frac1t$, then you get two integrals, one is this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2961277/integral-int-01-fracx21-ln1xx4-x21dx and one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2802487/integral-int-01-frac-sqrt-x-ln-x-x2-x1dx

Comment: The link you provided for $I_6$ only shows me how to do $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(x^2)}{x^4+x^2+1}dx$$ but doesn't actually help me with $I_6$.

Comment: @clathratus Substitute $x=\frac1t$ then add what you get with the initial integral. Thus you get: $$2I_6=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x^4+x^2+1}-\int_0^\infty\frac{(x^2-1)\arctan x}{x^4+x^2+1}dx $$
The first one is trivial, and for the second one integrate by parts followed by the substitution $x=\tan t$. Afterwards I suggest to use Feynman's trick.

Comment: wait nevermind. Thank you for all the help:)

Comment: @Zacky Got any hints for the last one? Through substitution, I've worked it down to
$$4\int_2^\infty \frac{\sin\sqrt{x^2-4}}{x}dx$$
but I've no idea how to do that one.

Comment: @Frpzzd a proof via residue theorem (not a fan) is found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3058069/integral-for-the-new-year-2019. 

I was about to post another way  (using real methods), but I realised I am missing something and gave up. I basically substituted $x-\frac{1}{x}=t$.

Comment: @Zacky Yeah, I'm not a fan of the RT either. I've reduced it to the integral
$$2\int_0^\infty \frac{x\sin(x)}{x^2+4}dx$$
which is a classic that can be done with the RT. Want to try and find another way using real methods?

Comment: @Frpzzd well, using the substitution: $x=2t$ it reduces to $\int_0^\infty \frac{t\sin (2t)}{t^2+1}dt$. I have a proof using real methods here: https://imgur.com/a/BhrHLx6, only that $t=2$ in the photo, but sure maybe there are other nice proofs.

Comment: @Zacky Oh yeah, looks like you have one. Nice!

Comment: @Frpzzd  Here is another one that you might like: $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2}dx$$

Comment: The way I solve it is similar to this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/365671/515527 , but  I got confused at this row: $$2 \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)}{1+x^2} \mathrm{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{2 \cos(u)}{1+x_+(u)^2} \frac{x_+^\prime(u)}{2} \mathrm{d}u + \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{2 \cos(u)}{1+x_-(u)^2} \frac{x_-^\prime(u)}{2} \mathrm{d}u$$

Comment: Could I have some help on $I_{14}$? I've 'reduced' it to $$I_{14}=\frac\pi4\ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}\right)-\int_0^{1/\sqrt2}\frac{\arcsin(x)}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx$$ but I don't know how to continue with the remaining integral. It is fairly evident that there is an intimate connection between $I_{14}$ and $\mathrm{Cl}_2$ but I am having trouble finding it exactly. Would it have something to do with $\sinh^{-1}(\sin x)=\ln\left(\sin(x)+\sqrt{1+\sin^2(x)}\right)$?

Comment: @clathratus try to apply Feynman's trick from the start.

Comment: uuuuuhhhhh, how? setting $\int_0^{\pi/4}\sinh^{-1}(\sin ax)dx$ isn't very helpful, and neither is $\int_0^{\pi/4}\sinh^{-1}(a\sin x)dx$.

Comment: Hmm, the second one should be helpful. I'll  see tomorrow.

Answer (score 8):

You might find a lot of *crazy* integrals and series in the book, **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**. A few examples of integrals,

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \cot (x) \log (\cos (x)) \log ^2(\sin (x))  \operatorname{Li}_3\left(-\tan ^2(x)\right) \textrm{d}x$$
$$
=\frac{109}{128}\zeta(7)-\frac{23}{32}\zeta(3)\zeta(4)+\frac{1}{16}\zeta(2) \zeta(5);$$
$$
\int_0^{\log(1+\sqrt{2})} \coth (x)  \log (\sinh (x)) \log \left(2-\cosh ^2(x)\right)\text{Li}_2\left(\tanh ^2(x)\right) \textrm{d}x$$
$$
=\frac{73}{128}\zeta(5)-\frac{17}{64}\zeta(2)\zeta(3);$$
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\displaystyle\log^2(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)}{1+x} \textrm{d}x$$
$$=\frac{1}{36} \log ^6(2)-\frac{1}{6}\log ^4(2)\zeta (2)+\frac{7}{24} \log ^3(2) \zeta (3)+\frac{5}{8}\log ^2(2) \zeta (4)-\frac{581}{48} \zeta (6)$$
$$
-\frac{7}{8} \log (2) \zeta (2)\zeta (3)-\frac{79}{64} \zeta^2 (3);$$

$$
\sin (\theta)\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\int_0^1 \frac{\displaystyle x}{(1-x) \left(1-2 x \cos (\theta)+x^2\right)} (\zeta (m+1)-\text{Li}_{m+1}(x)) \textrm{d}x$$
$$
=(-1)^{m-1}  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{k+1}}{(k+1)^{m+1}}\sin\left(\frac{k \theta}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{(k+1)\theta}{2}\right)$$
$$
+(-1)^{m-1}\sum_{i=2}^{m} (-1)^{i-1}\zeta(i)\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\displaystyle \sin\left(\frac{k\theta}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{(k+1) \theta}{2}\right)}{(k+1)^{m-i+2}};$$
$$\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\int_0^1\frac{x(\cos(\theta)-x)}{(1-x)(1-2x\cos(\theta)+x^2)}(\zeta (m+1)-\text{Li}_{m+1}(x))\textrm{d}x$$
$$
=(-1)^{m-1}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{k+1}}{(k+1)^{m+1}}\sin\left(\frac{k\theta}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{(k+1)\theta}{2}\right)$$
$$
+(-1)^{m-1}\sum_{i=2}^{m}(-1)^{i-1} \zeta(i)\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\displaystyle \sin\left(\frac{k\theta}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{(k+1)\theta}{2}\right)}{ (k+1)^{m-i+2}}.$$

A few examples of series (which you may also transform into some fancy integrals if you wish to),

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n^2}\left(\frac{ H_1}{1^3}+\frac{H_2}{2^3}+\cdots +\frac{H_n}{n^3} \right)=10\zeta(7)+\frac{9}{2}\zeta(2)\zeta(5)-\frac{23}{2}\zeta(3)\zeta(4);$$
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n^3}\left(\frac{H_1}{1^2}+\frac{H_2}{2^2}+\cdots +\frac{H_n}{n^2} \right)=\frac{23}{2}\zeta(3)\zeta(4)-\frac{11}{2}\zeta(2)\zeta(5)-4\zeta(7);$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n^2}{n^2}\left(\frac{H_1}{1^2}+\frac{H_2}{2^2}+\cdots +\frac{H_n}{n^2} \right)=\frac{45}{16}\zeta(7)-\frac{7}{2}\zeta(2)\zeta(5)+\frac{17}{2}\zeta(3)\zeta(4);$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n^2}\left(\frac{H_1^2}{1^2}+\frac{H_2^2}{2^2}+\cdots +\frac{H_n^2}{n^2} \right)=\frac{93}{8} \zeta(7)+\frac{11}{2}\zeta(2)\zeta(5)-\frac{51}{4}\zeta(3)\zeta(4);$$
$$
\zeta(4)$$
$$
=\frac{8}{5}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n H_{2 n}}{n^2}+\frac{64}{5}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{ \left(H_{2 n}\right)^2}{ (2 n+1)^2}+\frac{64}{5}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_{2 n}}{(2 n+1)^3}$$
$$
-\frac{8}{5}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\left(H_{2 n}\right){}^2}{ n^2}-\frac{32}{5}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n H_{2 n}}{(2 n+1)^2}-\frac{64}{5}\log(2)\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_{2 n}}{(2 n+1)^2}-\frac{8}{5}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_{2 n}^{(2)}}{ n^2}.$$

Extremely crazy integrals you may also find in the paper [The derivation of eighteen special challenging logarithmic integrals by Cornel Ioan Valean](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/334598773_The_derivation_of_eighteen_special_challenging_logarithmic_integrals).

I'm sure a lot of crazy integrals you'll also meet in the sequel of the book **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series** since the author prepares a continuation of this book.

Comment: WOAH!! This is very impressive! I will have to buy that book! Thanks for the great answer (+1)

Answer (score 7):

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\prod_{k=1}^n\operatorname{sinc}{\theta\over(2k-1)}d\theta=\pi ,$$*provided* $n\in{1 ... 7}$ ... for $n\geq8$, it starts being $<π$ by the most *miniscule* amounts!

Comment: Really interesting! where can I learn more?

Comment: It's actually called _the Borwein integral_. I strongly recommend the works of Peter Borwein in this connection - you'd _love_ it! There's _heaps_ of these crazy integrals in his works, & he's a specialist in unlimited precision arithmetic. He has an algorithm for finding closed-form expressions given a decimal expansion, that finds with a certain probability - rapidly increasing with number of digits - the peak-probability closed-form ... like if you were to say "hmmm - that _looks like_ the square-root of ζ(3)!", or something - but _systematised_. And _Ising_ integrals ... and ... and ... !

Comment: Wow thank you for this! I'll certainly look into that. :)

Comment: You're _very_ welcolme ... I _well_ -understand the compulsion!

Comment: I have noticed that you are very enthusiastic about cool integral identities, and I was wondering if you'd like to collaborate on an integral document with user @DavidG and me. let me know :)

Comment: @Clathratus -- I presume you mean me? I like the sound of the idea! Quite likely ... if it means I get an endless supply of the "meat that you know not of", to paraphrase a certain prophet perched on the edge of a well in Samaria!

Comment: Great! My email is joverton2020@gmail.com. I will contact you with David and we'll bring you to the document!

Comment: Wait I messed up... You need to contact me/tell me your email so I can take you to the document

Comment: Use _eis.aen.hypaegon@gmail.com_ ¶ (It's _Koine Greek_ ... it means _to which they had gone_.)

Comment: I look forward to communiqué with you soon. This very moment is not practical ... in fact it's only by a fluke that you caught me when you did, really!

Comment: @Clathratus -- what I'll do for now, I think, is get it sorted _just why_ that Borwein integral has it's property - afterall, I've quoted the result without any proof! Got sufficient material on it - and it appears within my measure. It's immediately less mysterious reflecting that the Fourier transform of _sinc_ is the _top-hat_ function ... so analysing it - if you have the integral of sinc×cos(a) (a being the _radius_ of the top-hat) it _suddenly_ becomes 0 the instant you have more than a full cycle of cos inside the central 'lobe' of _sinc_. And that is indeed what it's essentially about.

Answer (score 4):

I'm partial to the one in this question
[What is the Centroid of $z=\frac{1}{(1-i\tau)^{i+1}},\ \ \tau\in (-\infty,\infty)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2255301/what-is-the-centroid-of-z-frac11-i-taui1-tau-in-infty-infty) .

I found a solution, but it was hardly elegant.  A solution that doesn't use hypergeometric functions in the middle of the solution would be nice.

Comment: Hypergeometric function for not, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

This might not be a difficult integral but it made me come up with a new method to solve it so I think it's quite exotic.

Let’s do the general integral
$\displaystyle I(a,b)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(ax^{-2}+bx^{2})}dx$

Differentiate with respect to a

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial I}{\partial a}=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-2}e^{-(ax^{-2}+bx^{2})}dx$

Now differentiate with respect to b
$\displaystyle \frac{\partial^2 I}{\partial a \partial b}=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-2}x^{2}e^{-(ax^{-2}+bx^{2})}dx$

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial^2 I}{\partial a \partial b}=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(ax^{-2}+bx^{2})}dx$

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial^2 I}{\partial a \partial b}=I$

Thus our integral satisfies this PDE.This is a hyperbolic homogenous PDE. It is a second order PDE but it is first order with respect to each of the variables so we’ll need two boundary conditions to determine a unique solution.(In this case two asympotic BCs and one Drichlet boundary condition will be used).Keep this in mind we’ll need it later.

Let’s complete the square of expression in the exponential.

$\displaystyle I(a,b)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(ax^{-2}+bx^{2}-2\sqrt{ab}+2\sqrt{ab})}dx$

$\displaystyle I(a,b)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(\sqrt{a}x^{-1}-\sqrt{b}x)^{2}-2\sqrt{ab}}dx$

$\displaystyle I(a,b)=e^{-2\sqrt{ab}}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(\sqrt{a}x^{-1}-\sqrt{b}x)^{2}}dx$

Now let’s explore more of it’s properties.One thing to note is that this integral diverges(blows up) at b=0 but at a=0 it has a well known value. It is the Gaussian integral so

$\displaystyle I(0,b)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(bx^{2})}dx=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{b}}$

The negative exponential was extracted from the integral rather than the positive one beacause

$\displaystyle \lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(ax^{-2}+bx^{2})}dx=0$

and

$\displaystyle \lim_{a\to\infty}e^{-2\sqrt{ab}}=0$

So let’s assume that we assume that the solution to our PDE is of the form

$\displaystyle I(a,b)=e^{-2\sqrt{ab}}K(b)$

where K is a function of b(and diverges at b=0)

Let’s put this in the PDE

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial I}{\partial a}=-\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}e^{-2\sqrt{ab}}K(b)$

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial^2 I}{\partial a \partial b}=-\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}e^{-2\sqrt{ab}}K^{'}(b)-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{ab}}e^{-2\sqrt{ab}}K(b)+\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}e^{-2\sqrt{ab}}K(b)$

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial^2 I}{\partial a \partial b}=e^{-2\sqrt{ab}}(-\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}K^{'}(b)-\frac{K(b)}{2\sqrt{ab}}+K(b))$

As
$\displaystyle \frac{\partial^2 I}{\partial a \partial b}=I$

So

$\displaystyle e^{-2\sqrt{ab}}(-\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}K^{'}(b)-\frac{K(b)}{2\sqrt{ab}}+K(b))=e^{-2\sqrt{ab}}K(b)$

$\displaystyle -\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}K^{'}(b)-\frac{K(b)}{2\sqrt{ab}}+K(b)=K(b)$

$\displaystyle -\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}K^{'}(a)=\frac{K(b)}{2\sqrt{ab}}$

$\displaystyle K^{'}(b)=-\frac{K(b)}{2b}$

This is a separable ODE.Let’s solve it

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{K}dK=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{b}db$

Let’s integrate

$\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{K}dK=-\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{b}db$

$\displaystyle \ln(K)=-\frac{1}{2}\ln(b)+C$

$\displaystyle \ln(K)=\ln(b^{-\frac{1}{2}})+C$

$\displaystyle K=e^{C}b^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

Let
$\displaystyle v=e^{C}$

So

$\displaystyle K(b)=vb^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

Thus the solution is
$\displaystyle I(a,b)=ve^{-2\sqrt{ab}}b^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

This expression diverges at b=0 which is exactly what we wanted. Now let’s determine the constant v. As

$\displaystyle I(0,b)=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{b}}$

So
$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{b}}=vb^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{0}$
$v=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$

Thus the integral is

$\displaystyle \boxed{I(a,b)=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{b}}e^{-2\sqrt{ab}}}  (0\leqslant a,b)$

Comment: cool stuff! I really don't know anything about PDE's but this is sure exotic! Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some integrals collected by me and my friend pprime

I bring you many beautiful integrals that I have collected over time, I hope you enjoy them as much as I do.
If you want to answer one of these integrals.

1. Coxeter Integrals $\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {\arccos \left( {\frac{{\cos \theta }}{{1 + 2\cos \theta }}} \right)d\theta  = \frac{5}{{24}}\pi ^2 }$
2. $\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {\arccos \left( {\frac{1}{{1 + 2\cos \theta }}} \right)d\theta  = \frac{1}{8}\pi ^2 }$
3. $\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {\arccos \left( {\frac{{1 - \cos \theta }}{{2\cos \theta }}} \right)d\theta  = \frac{{11}}{{72}}\pi ^2 }$
4. For any $n$ natural number. Show that $\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi }{\frac{\left( 1+2\cos x \right)^{n}\cos nx}{3+2\cos x}dx}=\frac{2\pi }{\sqrt{5}}\left( 3-\sqrt{5} \right)^{n}$
5. Let $0<a<1$ Prove that $\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi }{\frac{\cos ^{2}3x}{1+a^{2}-2a\cos 2x}dx}=\frac{a^{2}-a+1}{1-a}\pi$
6. For $a>1$ Prove that $\int\limits_{-\pi }^{\pi }{\frac{x\sin x}{1+a^{2}-2a\cos x}dx}=\frac{\pi }{2}\ln \left( 1+\frac{1}{a} \right)$
7. $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{\ln \ln \frac{1}{x}}{\left( 1+x \right)^{2}}dx}=\frac{1}{2}\left( \ln \pi -\ln 2-\gamma  \right)$
8. $\int_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{\sinh x}{\cosh ^{2}x}\frac{dx}{x}}=\frac{4G}{\pi }$ where $G$ is the Catalan's constant
9. Let $z$ be a real number. Show that $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\log|z-e^{i\theta}|\,d\theta = \left\{              \begin{array}{ll}                0 &  \text{ si }|z|<1\\                   \log|z| &  \text{ si }|z|\ge1              \end{array}       \right.$
10. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\exp \left( -a^{2}x\left( \frac{x-6}{x-2} \right)^{2} \right)\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{a}$
11. Let $\alpha >0$ Prove that $I\left( \alpha  \right)=\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}{\arctan \left( \frac{2\alpha \sin ^{2}x}{\alpha ^{2}-1+\cos ^{2}x} \right)dx}=\pi \arctan \left( \frac{1}{2\alpha } \right)$
12. $\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{\log \left( {1 - x} \right)}}{x} \cdot \frac{{2z}}{{\log ^2 x + \left( {2\pi z} \right)^2 }}dx}  =  - \log \left( {\frac{{z!e^z }}{{z^z \sqrt {2\pi z} }}} \right),\;\;\operatorname{Re} \left( z \right) > 0$

13.$\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{1-x}{\log x}\cdot \left( x+x^{2}+x^{2^{2}}+... \right)dx}$

14. Let $a_k  > 0$ and $a_0  > \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {a_k }$. Show that $\int\limits_0^{ + \infty } {\prod\limits_{k = 0}^n {\frac{{\sin \left( {a_k x} \right)}}{x}dx} }  = \frac{\pi }{2}\prod\limits_{k = 1}^n {a_k }$
15. Let $0 < z < 1,\alpha  > 0,\beta  \in {\Bbb C}$
    $\int\limits_0^{ + \infty } {\sin \left( {\alpha t^{\frac{1}{z}}  + \beta } \right)} dt = \frac{{\Gamma \left( {z + 1} \right)}}
    {{\alpha ^z }}\sin \left( {\frac{{\pi z}}{2} + \beta } \right)$
16. $\operatorname{Re}\left( \alpha  \right)\ge 1$
    $\int\limits_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\left| {\sin x} \right|^{\alpha  - 1} \frac{{\sin x}}{x}} dx = 2^{\alpha  - 1} \frac{{\Gamma ^2 \left( {\frac{\alpha }{2}} \right)}}{{\Gamma \left( \alpha  \right)}}$
17. $\int\limits_0^1 {\sin \left( {\pi x} \right)} x^x \left( {1 - x} \right)^{1 - x} dx = \frac{{\pi e}}{{24}}$
18. $\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi }{4}} {\frac{{x^3 }}{{\sin ^2 x}}} dx = \frac{{3\pi }}{4}G - \frac{{\pi ^3 }}{{64}} + \frac{{3\pi ^2 }}
    {{32}}\log 2 - \frac{{105}}{{64}}\varsigma \left( 3 \right)$
19. Let $\theta  > 0$
    $\int\limits_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\left| {\cos \theta x} \right|}}{{1 + x^2 }}dx}  = 4\cosh \theta \arctan e^{ - \theta }$
20. Let $\alpha  \geqslant 0,\theta  \in {\Bbb C}\backslash \pi {\Bbb Z}$
    $\int\limits_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\cos \alpha x}}{{1 + 2\cos \theta x + x^2 }}dx}  = \frac{\pi }{{\sin \theta }}\frac{{\cos \left( {\alpha \cos \theta } \right)}}{{e^{\alpha \sin \theta } }}$
21. Show that $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}{\frac{d\theta }{1+\sin ^{2}\tan \theta }}=\frac{\pi }{2\sqrt{2}}\left( \frac{e^{2}+3-2\sqrt{2}}{e^{2}-3+2\sqrt{2}} \right)$
22. Let $\theta \in \left[ 0,\frac{\pi }{2} \right)$ Prove that $\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }{\frac{\arctan x}{x^{2}-2x\sin \theta +1}dx}$
23. Given the function $y\left(x\right):\left [0,1\right]\to\left [0,1\right]$ continuous and decreasing such that $x^{a}-x^{b} = y^{a}-y^{b}$. Compute $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{\ln \left( y\left( x \right) \right)}{x}dx}$
24. $\int_{0}^{1}\left ( -1 \right )^{\left [ 1994x \right ] + \left [ 1995x \right ]}\binom{1993}{\left [ 1994x \right ]}\binom{1994}{\left [ 1995x \right ]}dx$
25. $\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{dx}}{{1 + {}_2F_1 \left( {\frac{1}{n},x;\frac{1}{n};\frac{1}{n}} \right)}}}  = \frac{{\log \left( {\frac{{2n}}{{2n - 1}}} \right)}}{{\log \left( {\frac{n}{{n - 1}}} \right)}}$
26. $\int\limits_0^{ + \infty } {W\left( {\frac{1}{{x^2 }}} \right)} dx = \sqrt {2\pi }$
27. $\int\limits_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{W\left( x \right)}}{{x\sqrt x }}} dx = 2\sqrt {2\pi }$
28. Let $\alpha ,\beta  \in \Re  + $. Integrate $ \int\limits_0^{ + \infty } {\left( {\exp \left( { - \theta ^\alpha  } \right) - \frac{1}{{1 + \theta ^\beta  }}} \right)\frac{{d\theta }}{\theta }}  =  - \frac{1}{\alpha }\gamma$ where $W$ is the Lambert W function
29. $\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {\frac{{\ln ^2 \sin x\ln ^2 \cos x}}{{\sin x\cos x}}dx}  = \frac{1}{4}\left( {2\zeta \left( 5 \right) - \zeta \left( 2 \right)\zeta \left( 3 \right)} \right)$
30. $\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {4\cos ^2 x\left( {\ln \cos x} \right)^2 dx}  =  - \pi \ln 2 + \pi \ln ^2 2 - \frac{\pi }{2} + \frac{{\pi ^3 }}{{12}}$
31. $\int\limits_0^1 {\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{dxdy}}{{\left( {\left[ {\frac{x}{y}} \right] + 1} \right)^2 }}} }  = \frac{1}{2}\left( {\zeta \left( 3 \right) + 1 - \zeta \left( 2 \right)} \right)$
32. $\int\limits_0^1 {\int\limits_0^1 {\ln \left( {1 - xy} \right)\ln x\ln ydxdy} }  = \zeta \left( 2 \right) + \zeta \left( 3 \right) + \zeta \left( 4 \right) - 4$
33. $\int\limits_0^1 {\int\limits_0^1 {...\int\limits_0^1 {\ln \left( {1 - \prod\limits_{1 \leqslant i \leqslant n} {x_i } } \right)\prod\limits_{1 \leqslant i \leqslant n} {\ln x_i } dx_1 dx_2 ...dx_n } } }  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{n - 1} \left( { - 2n + \sum\limits_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant 2n} {\zeta \left( k \right)} } \right)$
34. Prove that $\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {\arctan \left( {1 - \left( {\sin x\cos x} \right)^2 } \right)} dx = \pi \left( {\frac{\pi }
    {4} - \arctan \sqrt {\frac{{\sqrt 2  - 1}}{2}} } \right)$
35. Let $s>0$ and $\alpha \in \left( 0,1 \right)$. Prove that $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{\text{L}{{\text{i}}_{s}}\left( -x \right)}{{{x}^{1+\alpha }}}dx}=-\frac{\pi }{{{\alpha }^{s}}\sin \left( \pi \alpha  \right)}$
36. $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {\frac{{n!2^{2n\cos \left( \phi  \right)} }}{{\left| {\prod\limits_{k = 1}^n {\left( {2ne^{i\phi }  - k} \right)} } \right|}}} d\phi  = 2\pi$
37. $\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}-1}{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}+1}}{\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x^{2}-2\left( 15+8\sqrt{3} \right)x+1}}\cdot \frac{dx}{x-1}}=\frac{2}{3}\left( 2-\sqrt{3} \right)G$ where $G$ is the Catalan's constant
38. Let $0<r<1$ and $r<s$ Prove that $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{x}\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\log \left | \frac{1+2rsx+\left ( r^{2}+s^{2}-1 \right )x^{2}}{1-2rsx+\left ( r^{2}+s^{2}-1 \right )x^{2}} \right |dx=4\pi \arcsin r$
39. $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\cosh \left( \alpha \ln x \right)\ln \left( 1+x \right)\frac{dx}{x}}=\frac{1}{2\alpha }\left( \pi \csc \left( \pi \alpha  \right)-\frac{1}{\alpha } \right)$
40. Let $\alpha \ne 0$ be a real number. Prove that $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{\ln \tan ^{2}\left( \alpha x \right)}{1+x^{2}}dx}=\pi \ln \tanh \alpha$
41. Consider $a>0,\ b\in \Re$. Prove that $\int\limits_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\frac{{a^2 }}{{\left( {e^x  - ax - b} \right)^2  + \left( {a\pi } \right)^2 }}} dx = \frac{1}{{1 + W\left( {\frac{1}{a}e^{ - \frac{b}{a}} } \right)}}$
42. $\int_0^\pi  {\sin \left( {n\alpha } \right)\arctan \left( {\frac{{\tan \left( {\frac{\alpha }{2}} \right)}}{{\tan \left( {\frac{\varphi }{2}} \right)}}} \right)} d\alpha  = \frac{\pi }{{2n}}\left[ {\left( {\sec \left( \varphi  \right) - \tan \left( \varphi  \right))^n  - \left( { - 1} \right)^n } \right)} \right],\left| {n \in {\Bbb Z}^ +  ,0 < \varphi  < \frac{\pi }{2}} \right|$
43. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{\cos \alpha x-\cos \beta x}{\sin \theta x}\frac{dx}{x}}=\log \left( \frac{\cosh \frac{\beta \pi }{2\theta }}{\cosh \frac{\alpha \pi }{2\theta }} \right)$
44. $\int\limits_0^\pi  {\log \left( {1 - \cos x} \right)\log \left( {1 + \cos x} \right)dx}  = \pi \log ^2 2 - \frac{{\pi ^3 }}
    {6}$
45. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{\arctan x}{\sinh \left( \frac{\pi x}{2} \right)}dx}=4\log \Gamma \left( \frac{1}{4} \right)-2\log \pi -3\log 2$
46. $\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}{x\cot x\log \sin xdx}=-\frac{{{\pi }^{3}}}{48}-\frac{\pi }{4}{{\ln }^{2}}2$
47. $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\log \left( \text{arcsech}x \right)dx}=-\gamma -2\log 2-2\log \left( \frac{\Gamma \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)}{\Gamma \left( \frac{1}{4} \right)} \right)$
48. $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1-8{{x}^{2}}+16{{x}^{4}}}{1+7{{x}^{2}}-8{{x}^{4}}}}\exp \left( \frac{4x\sqrt{1-{{x}^{2}}}}{\sqrt{1+8{{x}^{2}}}} \right)dx}=e-1$
49. Let $\left| \Im \left( n \right) \right|<1$ Prove that $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{\cos \left( n\pi x \right)}{\cosh \left( \pi x \right)}\cdot {{e}^{-i\pi {{x}^{2}}}}dx}=\frac{1+\sqrt{2}\sin \frac{{{n}^{2}}\pi }{4}}{2\sqrt{2}\cosh \frac{n\pi }{2}}+i\frac{1-\sqrt{2}\cos \frac{{{n}^{2}}\pi }{4}}{2\sqrt{2}\cosh \frac{n\pi }{2}}$
50. Let f be a function of class $C'\left[ 0,a \right]$. Prove that $\int\limits_0^{2a} {\int\limits_0^{\sqrt {2ax - x^2 } } {\frac{{x\left( {x^2  + y^2 } \right)}}{{\sqrt {4a^2 x^2  - \left( {x^2  + y^2 } \right)^2 } }}f'\left( y \right)dydx} }  = \pi a^2 \left( {f\left( a \right) - f\left( 0 \right)} \right)$
51. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{\cos \alpha x}{x}\cdot \frac{\sinh \beta x}{\cosh \gamma x}dx}=\frac{1}{2}\log \left( \frac{\cosh \frac{\alpha \pi }{2\gamma }+\sin \frac{\beta \pi }{2\gamma }}{\cosh \frac{\alpha \pi }{2\gamma }-\sin \frac{\beta \pi }{2\gamma }} \right)\quad \left| \operatorname{Re}\left( \beta  \right) \right|<\left| \operatorname{Re}\left( \gamma  \right) \right|,\ \left| \operatorname{Re}\left( \beta  \right) \right|+\left| \operatorname{Im}\left( \alpha  \right) \right|<\left| \operatorname{Re}\left( \gamma  \right) \right|$
52. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{\sin \alpha x}{x}\cdot \frac{\sinh \beta x}{sinh\gamma x}dx}=\arctan \left( \tan \frac{\beta \pi }{2\gamma }\tanh \frac{\alpha \pi }{2\gamma } \right)\quad \left| \operatorname{Re}\left( \beta  \right) \right|<\left| \operatorname{Re}\left( \gamma  \right) \right|,\ \left| \operatorname{Re}\left( \beta  \right) \right|+\left| \operatorname{Im}\left( \alpha  \right) \right|<\left| \operatorname{Re}\left( \gamma  \right) \right|$
53. $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{x}{1+{{x}^{2}}}\cdot \arctan x\ln \left( 1-{{x}^{2}} \right)dx}=-\frac{{{\pi }^{3}}}{48}-\frac{\pi }{8}\ln 2+G\ln 2$
54. $\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}{\frac{\arctan \left( \alpha \sin x \right)}{\sin x}dx}=\frac{\pi }{2}{{\sinh }^{-1}}\alpha$
55. $\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}{\frac{{{x}^{2}}}{{{x}^{2}}+{{\log }^{2}}\left( 2\cos x \right)}dx}=\frac{\pi }{8}\cdot \left( 1-\gamma +\log 2\pi  \right)$
56. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\sin \left( {{x}^{2}} \right){{\ln }^{2}}xdx}=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi }}{64}\cdot {{\left( 4\ln 2+2\gamma -\pi  \right)}^{2}}$
57. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{{{e}^{-\alpha x}}\sin \left( \beta x \right){{x}^{s-1}}dx}=\frac{\Gamma \left( s \right)}{\sqrt{{{\alpha }^{2}}+{{\beta }^{2}}}}\cdot \sin \left( s\arctan \frac{\beta }{\alpha } \right)$
58. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{{{e}^{-\alpha x}}\cos \left( \beta x \right){{x}^{s-1}}dx}=\frac{\Gamma \left( s \right)}{\sqrt{{{\alpha }^{2}}+{{\beta }^{2}}}}\cdot \cos \left( s\arctan \frac{\beta }{\alpha } \right)$
59. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{1}{1+{{e}^{\pi x}}}\cdot \frac{x}{1+{{x}^{2}}}dx}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \left( \log 2-\gamma  \right)$
60. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{\cos \left( {{x}^{p}} \right)-{{e}^{-{{x}^{q}}}}}{{{x}^{1+r}}}dx}=\frac{\Gamma \left( 1-\frac{r}{p} \right)\Gamma \left( 1+\frac{r}{p} \right)-\Gamma \left( 1+\frac{r}{2p} \right)\Gamma \left( 1-\frac{r}{2p} \right)}{r\Gamma \left( 1+\frac{r}{p} \right)}$
61. $\int\limits_{\pi }^{+\infty }{\frac{\sin x}{x}dx}+\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{2\pi }^{+\infty }{\frac{\sin x}{x}dx}+\frac{1}{3}\int\limits_{3\pi }^{+\infty }{\frac{\sin x}{x}dx+...}=\frac{\pi }{2}\cdot \left( 1-\ln \pi  \right)$
62. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{\sin \left( \frac{\omega x}{2} \right)}{x\left( {{e}^{x}}-1 \right)}dx}=\frac{1}{4}\cdot \ln \left( \frac{\sinh \left( \pi \omega  \right)}{\pi \omega } \right)$
63. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{1-\cos x}{{{x}^{2}}}{{e}^{-kx}}dx}=\arctan \frac{1}{k}-k\cdot \ln \left( \frac{\sqrt{1+{{k}^{2}}}}{k} \right)$
64. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\sin xsin\sqrt{x}{{e}^{-\alpha x}}dx}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}\cdot \frac{\exp \left( -\frac{\alpha }{4}\cdot \frac{1}{1+{{\alpha }^{2}}} \right)}{\sqrt[4]{{{\left( 1+{{\alpha }^{2}} \right)}^{3}}}}\cdot \sin \left( \frac{3}{2}\arctan \frac{1}{\alpha }-\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{1+{{\alpha }^{2}}} \right)$
65. $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{1-{{x}^{2}}}{\left( 1+{{x}^{2}}{{y}^{2}} \right){{\ln }^{2}}\left( xy \right)}dxdy}}=-2\log \left( \frac{2\Gamma \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)}{\Gamma \left( \frac{1}{4} \right)} \right)$
66. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\sin \left( \frac{1}{{{x}^{2}}} \right){{e}^{-\alpha {{x}^{2}}}}dx}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{\alpha }}{{e}^{-\sqrt{2\alpha }}}\sin \sqrt{2\alpha }$
67. $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{\ln \left( {{x}^{2}} \right)}{\left( 1+{{x}^{2}} \right)\left( {{\pi }^{2}}+{{\ln }^{2}}x \right)}dx}=\ln 2-\frac{1}{2}$
68. $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{\ln \left( {{\pi }^{2}}+{{\ln }^{2}}x \right)}{1+{{x}^{2}}}dx}=\pi \ln \left( \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}\cdot \frac{\Gamma \left( \frac{1}{4} \right)}{\Gamma \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)} \right)$
69. $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{{{x}^{2}}-1}{\left( 1+{{x}^{2}}{{y}^{2}} \right){{\ln }^{2}}\left( xy \right)}dx}dx}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{2C}{\pi }+\ln \left( \frac{2\sqrt{2}\pi }{{{\Gamma }^{2}}\left( \frac{1}{4} \right)} \right)$
70. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{dx}{\left( {{x}^{2}}+\frac{{{\pi }^{2}}}{4} \right)\cosh x}}=\frac{2\ln 2}{\pi }$
71. $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{{{\left( tan{{h}^{-1}}x \right)}^{z}}dx}=\frac{\zeta \left( z \right)}{{{2}^{2z-1}}}\cdot \Gamma \left( z+1 \right)\left( {{2}^{z}}-2 \right)\quad z\in \mathbb{N},z\ge 2$
72. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{x{{e}^{-x}}{{\left( \int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}{\left( 1-{{e}^{x-x\csc t}} \right){{\sec }^{2}}tdt} \right)}^{2}}dx}=\frac{1}{3}$
73. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{{{e}^{-x}}\ln \ln \left( {{e}^{x}}+\sqrt{{{e}^{2x}}-1} \right)dx}=-\gamma +4\log \Gamma \left( \frac{1}{4} \right)-3\log 2-2\log \pi$
74. $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\left\{ \frac{x}{y} \right\}\left\{ \frac{y}{z} \right\}\left\{ \frac{z}{x} \right\}dxdydz}}}=1+\frac{\zeta \left( 2 \right)\zeta \left( 3 \right)}{6}-\frac{3\zeta \left( 2 \right)}{4}$
75. $\int\limits_{0}^{\pi }{x\cot \left( \frac{x}{4} \right)dx}=2\pi \log 2+8C$
76. $\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}{x{{2}^{s}}co{{s}^{s}}x\sin \left( sx \right)dx}=\frac{\pi }{4}\cdot \left( \gamma +\psi \left( s+1 \right) \right)$
77. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{{{x}^{s-1}}{{\left( \arctan x \right)}^{2}}dx}=\frac{\pi }{2s\sin \frac{\pi s}{2}}\cdot \left( \gamma +\psi \left( \frac{1-s}{2} \right)+2\log 2 \right)$
78. $\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}{xta{{n}^{s}}xdx}=\frac{\pi }{4\sin \frac{\pi s}{2}}\cdot \left( \psi \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)-\psi \left( \frac{1-s}{2} \right) \right)$
79. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{\exp \left( -{{x}^{2}} \right)}{{{\left( {{x}^{2}}+\frac{1}{2} \right)}^{2}}}dx}=\sqrt{\pi }$
80. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{1}{x}\left( \frac{\sinh \alpha x}{\sinh x}-\alpha {{e}^{-2x}} \right)dx}=\log \left( \frac{\pi }{\cos \frac{\alpha \pi }{2}{{\Gamma }^{2}}\left( \frac{\alpha +1}{2} \right)} \right)\quad \left| \alpha  \right|<1$
81. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{\ln \left( {{x}^{2}}+{{\alpha }^{2}} \right)}{\cosh x+\cos t}dx}=\frac{2\pi }{\sin t}\log \left( \frac{\Gamma \left( \frac{\alpha }{2\pi }+\frac{\pi +t}{2\pi } \right)}{\Gamma \left( \frac{\alpha }{2\pi }+\frac{\pi -t}{2\pi } \right)} \right)+\frac{2t}{\sin t}\ln 2\pi$
82. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{{{\left( \sinh \left( sx \right) \right)}^{2}}}{x{{\left( {{e}^{x}}-1 \right)}^{3}}}dx}=\log \left( \frac{2\pi s}{\sin \left( 2\pi s \right)} \right)\quad 0<s<\frac{1}{2}$
83. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{{{x}^{s-1}}\sinh \left( \pi x \right)}{{{\left( \cosh \left( \pi x \right)-1 \right)}^{3}}}dx}=\frac{\Gamma \left( s \right)}{3{{\pi }^{s}}}\cdot \left( \zeta \left( 4-s \right)-\zeta \left( 2-s \right) \right)$
84. $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\sqrt{{{x}^{2}}+{{y}^{2}}+{{z}^{2}}}dxdydz}}}=\log \left( \sqrt{3}+1 \right)-\frac{\log 2}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}-\frac{\pi }{24}$
85. $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{{{x}^{\alpha -1}}{{y}^{\beta -1}}}{\left( 1+xy \right)\log \left( xy \right)}dxdy}}=\frac{1}{\alpha -\beta }\cdot \log \left( \frac{\Gamma \left( \frac{\alpha }{2} \right)\Gamma \left( \frac{1}{2}+\frac{\beta }{2} \right)}{\Gamma \left( \frac{\beta }{2} \right)\Gamma \left( \frac{1}{2}+\frac{\alpha }{2} \right)} \right)$
86. $\int\limits_{-\infty }^{+\infty }{\frac{1}{1+\frac{{{x}^{2}}}{{{\alpha }^{2}}}}\cdot \prod\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty }{\frac{1+\frac{{{x}^{2}}}{{{\left( \beta +k \right)}^{2}}}}{1+\frac{{{x}^{2}}}{{{\left( \alpha +k \right)}^{2}}}}dx}}=\sqrt{\pi }\cdot \frac{\Gamma \left( \beta +1 \right)}{\Gamma \left( \alpha  \right)}\cdot \frac{\Gamma \left( \alpha +\frac{1}{2} \right)}{\Gamma \left( \beta +\frac{1}{2} \right)}\cdot \frac{\Gamma \left( \beta -\alpha +\frac{1}{2} \right)}{\Gamma \left( \beta -\alpha +1 \right)}\quad 0<\alpha <\beta +\frac{1}{2}$
87. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{1}{x}\left( \frac{\sinh \left( ax \right)}{\sinh x}-a{{e}^{-2x}} \right)dx}=\log \left( \frac{\pi }{\cos \left( \frac{a\pi }{2} \right){{\Gamma }^{2}}\left( \frac{a+1}{2} \right)} \right)$
88. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{{{x}^{2}}{{e}^{-{{x}^{2}}}}erf\left( x \right)\log xdx}=\frac{2-\log 2}{16}\sqrt{\pi }-\frac{\gamma +\log 2}{16\sqrt{\pi }}\left( \pi +2 \right)+\frac{G}{4\sqrt{\pi }}$
89. $\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}{\sin \left( 2nx \right)\sinh \left( a\sin x \right)\sin \left( a\cos x \right)dx}={{\left( -1 \right)}^{n+1}}\frac{\pi }{4}\cdot \frac{{{a}^{2n}}}{\left( 2n \right)!}$
90. Let $\beta >0$ and $\alpha \in \left( -\frac{\pi }{2},\frac{\pi }{2} \right)$. Prove that $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{{{e}^{-t\cos \alpha }}{{t}^{\beta -1}}\cos \left( t\sin \alpha  \right)dx}=\Gamma \left( \beta  \right)\cos \left( \beta \sin \alpha  \right)$
91. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{\ln \left( 1+x \right)\ln \left( 1+\frac{1}{{{x}^{2}}} \right)}{x}dx}=\pi G-\frac{3}{8}\zeta \left( 3 \right)$
92. $\int\limits_{-\infty }^{+\infty }{\int\limits_{-\infty }^{+\infty }{\text{sign}\left( x \right)\text{sign}\left( y \right){{e}^{-\frac{{{x}^{2}}+{{y}^{2}}}{2}}}\sin \left( xy \right)dxdy}=2\sqrt{2}\log \left( 1+\sqrt{2} \right)}$
93. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\left( \frac{x}{{{\log }^{2}}\left( {{e}^{{{x}^{2}}}}-1 \right)}-\frac{x}{\sqrt{{{e}^{{{x}^{2}}}}-1}{{\log }^{2}}\left( {{e}^{{{x}^{2}}}}-1 \right)}-\frac{x}{\sqrt{{{e}^{{{x}^{2}}}}-1}\log \left( {{\left( {{e}^{{{x}^{2}}}}-1 \right)}^{2}} \right)} \right)dx}=\frac{G}{\pi }$
94. $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{{{B}_{2n+1}}\left( x \right)\cot \left( \pi x \right)dx}=\frac{2\left( 2n+1 \right)!}{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{n+1}}{{\left( 2\pi  \right)}^{2n+1}}}\zeta \left( 2n+1 \right)$ where ${{B}_{2n+1}}\left( x \right)$ is the Bernoulli Polynomial
95. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{x}{1+{{x}^{4}}}\arctan \left( \frac{p\sin qx}{1+p\cos qx} \right)dx}=\frac{\pi }{2}\arctan \left( \frac{p\sin \left( \frac{q}{\sqrt{2}} \right)}{{{e}^{\frac{q}{\sqrt{2}}}}+p\cos \left( \frac{q}{\sqrt{2}} \right)} \right)$
96. Let $m\in \Re$ and $a\in \left( -1,1 \right)$ Calculate
    $\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi }{\frac{{{e}^{m\cos \theta }}\left( \cos \left( m\sin \theta  \right)-a\sin \left( \theta +m\sin \theta  \right) \right)}{1-2a\sin \theta +{{a}^{2}}}d\theta }$
97. Prove that $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{{{\left( xy \right)}^{s-1}}{{y}^{n}}}{\left( 1-xy \right)\log \left( xy \right)}dxdy}}=\frac{\Gamma '\left( s \right)}{\Gamma \left( s \right)}-\frac{\log \left( n! \right)}{n}$
98. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\sin \left( nx \right)\left( \cot x+\coth x \right){{e}^{-nx}}dx}=\frac{\pi }{2}\cdot \frac{\sinh \left( n\pi  \right)}{\cosh \left( n\pi  \right)-\cos \left( n\pi  \right)}$
99. $\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{3}}{{{\log }^{2}}\left( \frac{\sin x}{\sin \left( x+\frac{\pi }{3} \right)} \right)dx}=\frac{5{{\pi }^{3}}}{81}$
100. $\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi }{{{x}^{2}}\log \left( 1-\exp \left( ix \right) \right)dx}=2\pi \zeta \left( 4 \right)-8i{{\pi }^{2}}\zeta \left( 3 \right)$

100+1. Let $a\in \left( 0,1 \right)$ Prove that $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{\log \log \frac{1}{x}}{1+2x\cos \left( a\pi  \right)+{{x}^{2}}}dx}=\frac{\pi }{2\sin \left( a\pi  \right)}\left( a\log \left( 2\pi  \right)+\log \frac{\Gamma \left( \frac{1}{2}+\frac{a}{2} \right)}{\Gamma \left( \frac{1}{2}-\frac{a}{2} \right)} \right)$

Bonus

1. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{\cos x}{x}{{\left( \int\limits_{0}^{x}{\frac{\sin t}{t}dt} \right)}^{2}}dx}=-\frac{7}{6}\zeta \left( 3 \right)$
2. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{{{x}^{a-1}}\sin x}{\cos x+\cosh x}dx}={{2}^{1-\frac{a}{2}}}\Gamma \left( a \right)\sin \left( \frac{a\pi }{4} \right)\left( 1-{{2}^{1-a}} \right)\zeta \left( a \right)$
3. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{\cos \left( tx \right)}{\left( 1+{{x}^{2}} \right)\cosh \left( \frac{\pi x}{2} \right)}dx}=\cosh t\log \left( 2\cosh t \right)-t\sinh t$
4. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{{{t}^{s-1}}}{{{z}^{-1}}{{e}^{t}}-1}dt}=\Gamma \left( s \right)\text{L}{{\text{i}}_{s}}\left( z \right)$
5. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\exp \left( -2u \right)\left( \frac{1}{u\sinh u}-\frac{1}{{{u}^{2}}coshu} \right)du}=2-\log 2-\frac{4G}{\pi }$
6. $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{\sin \left( bt \right)}{t}{{e}^{-at}}\ln tdt}=-\left( \gamma +\frac{\ln \left( {{a}^{2}}+{{b}^{2}} \right)}{2} \right)\arctan \frac{b}{a}$
7. $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{\left( a-t \right)\ln \left( 1-t \right)}{1-2at+{{t}^{2}}}dt}=\frac{{{\pi }^{2}}}{12}-\frac{{{\left( \arccos a-\pi  \right)}^{2}}}{8}-\frac{{{\ln }^{2}}\left( 2-2a \right)}{8}$
8. $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{{{\left\{ \frac{1}{x} \right\}}^{2}}dx}=\ln \left( 2\pi  \right)-1-\gamma$
9. $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{{{\left\{ \frac{1}{x} \right\}}^{2}}\left\{ \frac{1}{1-x} \right\}dx}=2+\gamma -\ln \left( 4\pi  \right)$
10. $$\int\limits_{0}^{1}{{{\left\{ \frac{x}{y} \right\}}^{2}}dxdy}=\frac{1}{2}\ln \left( 2\pi  \right)-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{\gamma }{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

I like

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty } \frac{r \log \left(\frac{\frac{\frac{D^2}{4}+r^2}{D r}+1}{\frac{\frac{D^2}{4}+r^2}{D r}-1}\right)}{\frac{D^2}{4}+r^2} \, dr=\pi^2$$

where $D>0$ (no proof supplied).

If you make the mistake of trying to convert the $\log$ term to its series form, to attempt to integrate term by term, this integral becomes really crazy, an infinite almost fractal cascade of further self similar integrals with the series for $\pi/2$ gradually appearing out of the fog

$$1+\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{4}\right)+\frac{1}{7}\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{4}\frac{5}{6}\right)+...=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

You miss all this underlying structure sensibly driving via the mathematical motorway.

Comment: I don't get this. How is this integral any different from $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x\log\frac{x+1}{x-1}}{1+x^2}dx=? {\pi^2\over2} ?$$ Right! I agree through 'cheating' (evaluating it numerically) that it's so ... but I still say all that "D" business & putting it in a perversely complex form is a total red-herring! I get how there is a logarithmic singularity at x=±1 & how the imaginary part is an odd function between them.

Comment: You can derive using partial fraction representation the general case
$$I_n\equiv\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x^{2n}(1+x^2)}=(-1)^n\bigg({\pi\over4}+\sum_{k=1}^n{(-1)^k\over2k-1}\bigg)=\bigg|{\pi\over4}+\sum_{k=1}^n{(-1)^k\over2k-1}\bigg|=\sum_{k=0}^\infty{(-1)^k\over 2(n+k)+1}$$ whence $$\int_1^\infty\frac{x\log\frac{1+1/x}{1-1/x}}{1+x^2}dx=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty {I_n\over 2n+1}$$$$=$$$$2\sum_{n=0}^\infty{1\over 2n+1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty{(-1)^k\over 2(n+k)+1}$$

Comment: Likewise for the integral from 0 to 1 ... substitute $x=1/y$ & limits from 1 to $\infty$ & we get a similar series that begins at  $n=1 \therefore$ with $I_1$ in the numerator & $2n-1$ in the denominator. So we get $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x\log\big(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\big)}{1+x^2}$$$$=$$$$\frac{\pi}{2}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty{n\over n^2-{1\over4}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty{(-1)^k\over 2(n+k)+1}$$$$=$$$$\frac{π^2}{4} ,$$whence the integral over $(-\infty,\infty)$ is $\pi^2/2$. So we could numerically verify that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{n\over n^2-{1\over4}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty{(-1)^k\over 2(n+k)+1}={\pi\over8}(\pi-2) .$$

Comment: Just one last thing, and then I'm through - as this is only taking delight in seeing explicitly how the series all pan-out & fit together, really - I'm sure the proper way to do it is something like _Feynmann's trick_ or a _contour integral_, or whatever... but the value of the integral is __π²/2__ ... did you not put that in the first place & then edit it!? I'm _almost_ sure you did.

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey: The origin of this is an attempt to derive Coulombs law in a different way that is off-topic here. The physical integral is between $0$ and $\infty$, so was equal to $\pi^2/2$. $D$ is the charge separation. At the heart of my attempt at a physical model I ended up with a final integral that is independent of $D$ (the charge separation) which you have investigated in your comments. Physically the integral can be simplified because you can move the origin of the original volume integral from halfway between the charges to co-locate with one of the charges.

Comment: _That's_ where I got the confusion about the "/2" business: in your integral _as you give it_ it's argument is the _square_ of (thing) ... & I just took the square away & then forgot I'd done that. _Now_ I'll have a think about _the rest_ of what you've said!

Comment: I must confess - I can't 'reverse engineer' what it is you're attempting. When I see the logarithms, my first thought is that it's the potential generated by two infinite oppositely charged _line_ charges ... but then I can't imagine why you would then _integrate_ such a potential (afterall, potentials _are_ integrals, and they are usually _differentiated_), especially with a factor of x/(1+x^2) multiplying it. But then ... I suspect I am 'climbing the wrong tree' here!

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$\int_0^1x\left[{_2}F_1(\tfrac12,1;2;x)\right]^2dx=12-16\ln2,$$
$$\int_0^1 x\left[{_2}F_1(\tfrac13,\tfrac23;\tfrac32;x)\right]^3dx=\frac{27}{32},$$
$$\int_0^1x\left[{_3}F_2(\tfrac14,\tfrac12,\tfrac34;\tfrac23,\tfrac43;x)\right]^4dx=\frac{1792}{2187},$$
and
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{dtdxdz}{x^{1/2}(1-x)^{1/2}t^{1/4}(1-t)^{5/12}(1-txz)^{1/4}}=\frac{2^{9/4}\cdot11\sqrt{\pi}}{3^{19/8}}\frac{\Gamma(\tfrac13)}{\Gamma(\tfrac14)}\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1},$$ all from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3939416/583016).

---

Another cool one:

$$\int_0^\infty\left\{x-\log(2\sinh x)\right\}\cos^2(x)dx=\frac18\left[\frac{\pi^2}{3}+\pi\coth\pi-1\right]$$

Answer (score 0):

My favorite is:

$$∫(0, 1](-1)^{{\lfloor} {1}/{x^t} \rfloor} dx = 1 - 2η(1/t)$$

step 1: do $u = 1/x^t$

step 2: drag out constants

step 3: split integral from $[1, \infty)$ to ∑(n = 1 -> inf) (∫[n, n+1])

step 4: $(-1)^{\lfloor(u) \rfloor} = (-1)^n$

step 5: the remaining integrals are easy, use $∫x^n dx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$

step 6: some tedious series manipulations and transformations

step 7: use that $η(s) =$ ∑ (n = 1 -> inf) $((-1)^{n-1})/(n^s)$

step 8: if you followed instructions closely, you should get $1 - 2η(1/t)$

Comment: please format your answer using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), it is near impossible to understand in its current format