# How and where to learn crazy complicated integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

I am curious about what books or online courses I could try to learn how to solve some crazy integrals. I’ll add some pictures to demonstrate what I’m talking about. Any recommendations and tips would be greatly appreciated.[Crazy integral examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEsQF.png)

Comment: Inside Interesting Integrals by Paul J. Nahin is a great read. Also, if you could link the MSE post where you sent your screenshot from, that'd be much appreciated!

Comment: @DanielGeyfman
This is the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3027621/request-for-crazy-integrals).
To be honest I find Math Stack Exchange itself a place to find and learn Crazy Complicated Integrals.
Though it also depends on your knowledge, what you may or may not know.

Comment: Many of these look like they arise from complex contour integration and the Residue Theorem. Should be plenty of online courses on those.